# Angular select input does not change model property when using it with web workers

Tags: angular, web-worker

I have the following component in Angular:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form>
      <select name="selectedValue" id="selectedValue" [(ngModel)]="selected">
        <option value="-1"></option>
        <option *ngFor="let v of [1,2,3]"
          [value]="1">{{v}}
        </option>
      </select>
      <p>The selected number is {{selected}}</p>
    </form>
  `,
  providers: []
})

export class AppComponent {
  private selected = -1;
}
```

When testing on the browser, the `selected` property won't get updated when the user selects an option. So, the paragraph in the output is always equal to `The selected number is -1`.

If I remove the `ngFor` inside the `select`, the `select` input will respond.

This component is also run inside a web worker. If I go back to a `BrowserModule`, the `select` input will also respond.

The code is available in the following [github repo](https://github.com/koslambrou/angular-cli-web-worker-select-problem).

**UPDATE:**

I changed `[value]="1"` to `[value]="v"`, but the output is always `The selected number is -1`.

Answer (score 0):

```ts
[value]="1"
```

the value is constant for all options and equals to `1`. Since the model is updated to the options' value after you select an option this value is updated to the model. If you have the same value in options you can't see which option was selected. The values should be unique to correspond the selected value that reflects the `ngModel` to pre-select the `selected` value of this property.

Change the value to

```ts
[value]="v"
```

Comment: `[value]="1"` is refering to the number, not to the property `1`. Without using web workers, the posted code works as it outputs `The selected number is 1` when selecting 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: I changed it, but same result. The output is always `The selected number is -1`.  (my mistake in my last comment).

Comment: Yes you should change this, first time when I answered this I have created a plunk, but dropped it. It's very clear how it should work. The only problem that you *can't* do it.